# Weird connection between CoInitializeSecurity() and Media Foundation Encoders

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664404/media-foundation-codec-error-while-trying-h265-succeeds-in-h-264).

Take this code:

```
CoInitializeSecurity(0, -1, 0, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS, 0, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
UINT32 count = 0;
IMFActivate** ppActivate = NULL;    // Array of activation objects.
MFTEnumEx(
    MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER,
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL,
    0,      // Input type
    0,       // Output type
    &ppActivate,
    &count
);
CoTaskMemFree(ppActivate);
```

Without the `CoInitializeSecurity`, the count is 9 in my system. When `CoInitializeSecurity` is called with RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS, some of the codecs are not anymore available.

The problem is that I need to set the security to anonymous for loading remote plugins. Is there anyway to override this behaviour?

If not, is there a way to reverse the effects of CoInitializeSecurity when trying to use one of the MF encoders?

Comment: Where is your `MFStartup` relative to these mentioned API calls?

Comment: At app start, before CoInitializeSecurity()

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis With and without calling `CoInitializeSecurity`, both of them result in "count is 7". Could you check which codecs are not anymore available with `CoInitializeSecurity` called?

Comment: Codec HEVCVideoExtensionEncoder, MF_MT_SUBTYPE   MFVideoFormat_HEVC. This codec does not appear in the enumeration list. Basically, It started due to the fact that I could not generate an HEVC/H265 video from media foundation, and it suddendly worked when I elimiated the call to CoInitializeSecurity.

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that the codecs are packaged as Windows Store apps. Reduced COM privileges are apparently blocking enumeration of such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFTEnumEx needs high token to than **ANONYMOUS** level. The workaround for this issue is that you can create another thread for anonymous and implements and use the default level in the main thread as usual.

For the detailed about this issue, you can also refer to link below:

[Media Foundation API primitive styling of WinRT windows.mediaCodec](http://alax.info/blog/)