# Media Foundation cannot initialise transform (cannot connect to Windows Update)

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation, windows-update

I have a Media Foundation based video decoder that works with the HEVC Codec from Microsoft.

On my development machine it works just fine.

However, on our production machines (which are very locked down devices with integrated GPUs and no Internet connections), attempting to activate the single transform that is found (the HEVC one I want to use) fails.

The error code returned is:
`0x800704CF - The network location cannot be reached.`

Some investigations suggest this is because Media Foundation (or the HEVC Codec or something associated with it) is trying to connect to `sls.update.microsoft.com`.  And if it can't do that, it fails the activation.

My question is:  How can I stop this?

Or more specifically, because I probably can't stop this, how do I fool Media Foundation into thinking it has already tried and succeeded in connecting?

On my development machine, it doesn't look like Media Foundation is making this connection attempt every time the application starts - it appears to be a one time thing, so presumably there's a registry key being written that I can force/fake on our production machines.

I've been hunting through the registry on my development machine, but haven't located anything that could be related - yet.  (Maybe someone knows where I should be looking?)

Or is there an official way to run Media Foundation on a machine with no Internet connection?

Comment: The Microsoft HEVC codec is installed from the Windows Store, it's a bit special https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368680/weird-connection-between-coinitializesecurity-and-media-foundation-encoders. So, first of all, have you installed it? If yes, then are you sure your machine is picking this one up? If you just ask to decode HEVC to media foundation you may get another one (NVidia, Intel, etc.)? On what MF call do you get the error? Does MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL, ...) work and show it?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, the HEVC codec is installed through its appxBundle as part of the install process for our application.  `MFTEnumEx` returns a single item, the HEVC decoder, which subsequently fails on the `ActivateObject` call.  Basically, I can reproduce this problem on a Windows VM without Internet access.  As soon as I give it Internet access everything starts working.

Comment: I don't reproduce, you can test this app https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsmmEDGvydk2v2EZM1ef7uRHnjeB?e=3rA6mU it should show all MFT on a PC, this is what it shows on a Windows 10 VM with or w/o network https://pastebin.com/raw/3QzeswuB you can see activate HEVCVideoExtensionEncoder's attributes

Comment: @SimonMourier I updated your test app to enumerate decoders (as that's what I'm interested in).  I ran it twice, once on a machine without any Internet connection, and then again on the same machine after connecting it to the Internet.  (That was the only change to the code and the machine.)  Results here:  https://pastebin.com/LwE7wLWG

Basically, the HEVC extension "activates" itself once it can connect to the Microsoft servers.  Before that it's dead in the water.  As mentioned in the original post, it only needs to do this once.  Afterwards it works fine regardless of the network state.

Comment: I have the exactly same list of decoders with or w/ the network (win10, win11) https://pastebin.com/raw/ZaSRUPwn I have also tested to 1) deinstall hevc exts, 2) stop network, 3) reinstall it (w/o network) and 4) try the program (w/o network), and it still activates fine. Seems it happens at higher (or lower) level than media foundation, maybe related to the machine, how you install Windows, software, etc.  FWIW, I use Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_2.1.451.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.AppxBundle to install it.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah, but the presence of an Internet connection doesn't make a difference if the codec has phoned home at least once.  It's just that first time that's important.  After that, it doesn't seem to matter.  I.e., install and use it on a clean install of Windows that's never had an Internet connection, and it doesn't work.  As soon as it's been allowed to connect to sls.update.microsoft.com once, it'll continue working regardless.  (As far as I can tell it doesn't attempt the connection again.)

Comment: Ok, indeed with a fresh VM I can reproduce it. I don't have the same error (I get 0x80072ee7 WININET_E_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) but it's the same idea. When debugging it's clear it's a licensing issue https://pastebin.com/raw/WYDqzznC the code is calling this `StoreContext.AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackageAsync` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.acquirestorelicenseforoptionalpackageasync and fails which makes sense. May be this would help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-offline-apps

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah, right.  That makes sense.  Thanks.  (If you want to formulate that into an answer, I can accept it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [H.265 / HEVC Video Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-265---hevc-video-decoder) is in fact available through a Microsoft Windows Store application named [HEVC Video Extensions](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nmzlz57r3t7) (installed in `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension...`). It consists today of two binaries: `HEVCDECODER_STORE.dll` and `mfH265Enc.dll`.

Note this is not a free application. There used to also exist a 'HEVC from Device Manufacturer' that has disappeared from the store that was free. It's not clear the exact technical differences between the two, that may be due to HEVC licensing issues (see [High Efficiency Video Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding)).

On a Windows installation where this "application" has never been installed, it will try to contact Microsoft licensing server. If the server cannot be contacted because you don't have an available Internet connection, this step will fail. This is where you may get the `0x800704CF` (`ERROR_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE`) error, and I get `0x80072ee7` (`WININET_E_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`)...

Note if you installed it once, then the license seems to stay even if you uninstall the application afterwards.

The licensing issue can be seen while debugging a simple application using the HEVC Media Foundation IMFActivate interface and trying to use it like this:

```
IMFActivate* hevcActivate ... gotten from somewhere
IMFTransform* hevcTransform;
hevcActivate->QueryInterface(IID_IMFTransform, (void**)&hevcTransform);
```

This is what's displayed in the debugger output:

```
...
ModLoad: 00007fff`71d10000 00007fff`71f47000   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`bdad0000 00007fff`bdaf9000   C:\Windows\System32\Cabinet.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`bac20000 00007fff`baedc000   C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`a3970000 00007fff`a3ac3000   C:\Windows\System32\webservices.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`be070000 00007fff`be17a000   C:\Windows\System32\WINHTTP.dll
 info:Setting MSA Client Id for Token requests: {f0c62012-2cef-4831-b1f7-930682874c86}  (0x80004005)    [WinStoreAuth::AuthenticationInternal::SetMsaClientId]
onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\auth\lib\winstoreauth.cpp(267)\Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll!00007FFF71D16DBE: (caller: 00007FFF71E3465F) LogHr(1) tid(148c) 80004005 Unspecified error
    Msg:[Setting MSA Client Id for Token requests: {f0c62012-2cef-4831-b1f7-930682874c86}] [WinStoreAuth::AuthenticationInternal::SetMsaClientId]
 info:Windows::Services::Store::StoreContextFactory::GetDefault() invoked. (CV:5TroTyea8UKFylH5.2)  [Windows::Services::Store::StoreContextFactory::GetDefault]
ModLoad: 00007fff`bf2c0000 00007fff`bfa90000   C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
 info:StoreContextServer::Initialize: packageFullName = , productStoreId = , isLicensed = false, isAppContainer = false [Windows::Services::Store::Internal::StoreContextServer::Initialize]
 info:Windows::Services::Store::StoreContext::AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackageAsync invoked. (CV:5TroTyea8UKFylH5.2.3) [Windows::Services::Store::StoreContext::AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackageAsync]
ERROR:  (0x80070057)    [ClientProcessUtils::GetCallingAppPackageFamilyName]
ModLoad: 00007fff`bd2a0000 00007fff`bd2b6000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
(c98.1ac4): Unknown exception - code 80072ee7 (first chance)
ERROR:ChkHr(hr) (0x80072ee7)    [Windows::Services::Store::Internal::StoreContextServer::AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackage]
ERROR:ChkHr(storeContextServer->AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackage( optionalPfn.Get(), spStorePackageLicenseLostCallback.Get(), &_valid))    (0x80072ee7)    [Windows::Services::Store::StorePackageLicense::RuntimeClassInitialize]
ERROR:  (0x80070057)    [ClientProcessUtils::GetCallingAppPackageFamilyName]
ERROR:ChkHr(MakeAndInitialize<StorePackageLicense>( &_pStorePackageLicense, _pOptionalPackage.Get(), _storeContext.Get() )) (0x80072ee7)    [Windows::Services::Store::AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackageOperation::DoWork]
(c98.148c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 00007fff`71cc0000 00007fff`71d0c000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WebpImageExtension_1.1.522.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\x64\mswebp_store.dll
(c98.148c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
...
```

We see that underlying code uses the [StoreContext.AcquireStoreLicenseForOptionalPackageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.acquirestorelicenseforoptionalpackageasync) WinRT's method and fails with `ERROR:ChkHr(hr) (0x80072ee7)`.

So, it's a licensing issue. Maybe it's possible to distribute this package offline, this is a hint [Distribute offline apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-offline-apps), not sure how/if it works.

Comment: The technical differences have to be around software implementation of the decoder. When the decoding happens at hardware, with GPU decoder, then it's free as licensing fee is already included into hardware. When it comes to brining the software decoder into the system, here comes paid store app.

Comment: @RomanRyltsov - hmmm. I didn't thought about that. On my PC, MFTEnumEx reports NVidia & Intel hardware HEVC encoders (plus Microsoft HEVC) but no HVEC hardware decoder except the Microsoft one, that sounds strange doesn' it? Is Microsoft decoder can still decode hardware with hardware vendors not being able to do it?

Comment: Video decoding takes place via DXVA2 code path. For this reason you never see decoders from hardware vendors. Microsoft's MFT handles both software and hardware assisted decoding. Encoders are different, HW vendors supply their own implementations with their driver package. Mictosoft's encoder is putely software. Encoders are separate MFTs from MF standpoint, you can choose the one you want. Decoder MFT is always the Microsoft's one because it's a wrapper over DXVA2.